# What are some good, free, hosted services to use for a Play-By-Wiki game?

Tags: game-recommendation, tools, online-roleplaying, play-by-post

Aside from a highly specialized and purpose-built website, perhaps the best option I can think of for managing an asynchronous online RPG is "Play By Wiki".  I've found there's a great number of services out there, which offer varying levels of support for setting up this kind of game.

Here's what I'm looking for in a hosted Play-By-Wiki solution:

- Features in this list must be included at no cost.
- Edit permissions are granted only to specified users.
- Read permissions may be public.
- Unlimited number of wiki pages.
- Unlimited number of community users.
- Site is hosted on the service provider's servers and is fully functional "out-of-the-box".
- Storage space available for file attachments.
- No programming background or experience necessary.  WYSIWYG editor preferred.
- "Talk" section for each page, to discuss actions before posting to the wiki.

Some things that would be good to have, but are not mandatory (can be found on other sites, managed separately, or disregarded entirely):

- Map and Character management tools.
- Secure dice rolling.
- Combat Manager

What services are out there that meet this criteria?

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like Obsidian Portal might suit your needs. If you take a look at [the features list on the signup page](https://www.obsidianportal.com/signup):

- Free to use
- GM can have secret pages
- The wiki can be public or private
- No mention of page or user limits
- Site hosted by Obsidian Portal and is out-of-the-box
- Maps and images can be uploaded

  - Special map-handling tools included
- NPC and PC management

Comment: Definitely check out Obsidian Portal. We're not built for "play by wiki", since it's mainly for in-person games, but we have a lot of the features you're talking about. Take a look and see what you think.

Answer (score 3):

I know quite a few people using [Wikidot](http://www.wikidot.com/) to run games.  Not necessarily play-by-Wiki games, but there's nothing there that would interfere with such a game and it has features that would support it like account privileges and the like.  Downside: if you don't have an ad blocker the page can get cluttered with ads.

Answer (score 0):

playbyweb.com is something I don't here people mention too much, but it is easy to have both IC and OOC threads as well as threads for just dice which is supported in the code of the site. They also offer a limited number of Avatar pics to choose from and it works with basic html so of course if you see nothing you like you can always post your own. There is not a big community on there, but I would suggest finding players on another site and giving them a link. Google Docs has been used in conjunction with playbyweb.com in the past too as you can invite a wide number of people to edit documents. When I played Roll20 games we used dropbox to share documents but I imagine Google docs would work better.